# How to make Hyperlinks in Excel open in Browser

Tags: c#, excel, wpf, hyperlink, office-interop

I'm creating an ExcelSheet by using the Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel which contains a bunch of Links to Locations that are only for authorized access.
The Link is created by this code:

```
Sheet.Cells[i + 1, "C"] = "=HYPERLINK(\"https://priavtesite.com/user/item/" + item.ID + "\", \"Click Me!\")";
```

The Excel works and its a Hyperlink.

But if I want to open the Link there is an Error:

> Unable to open https://privatesite.com/user/item/123. The internet site reports that the item you requested could not be found. (HTTP/1.0 404)

Which is OK, because Excel is not logged in.

It happens no matter

- whats the default browser
- if you are logged in to the account on the default browser

My Question:
How can I format the cell that it opens the Link in a Browser directly before checking if the site is available or not.
Or do I need to set a setting in Excel?

Thank You!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It (kind of) works now.
I'm not using `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel` anymore, but `Syncfusion.XlsIO`.

I'm now doing this

```
worksheet.Range[i + 1, 3].Text = "=HYPERLINK(\"https://privatesite.com/user/item/" + item.ID + "\"; \"Click Me!\")";
```

When the Excel-Sheet is ready, I need to manually put focus on every cell and click Enter, to make it a Hyperlink.